# Combine a tkinter Filedialog with json.dump

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I've spent the better part of an hour researching this, as I am sure, very simple problem. 
All I am trying to do is export a dictionary from my program using `json.dump()`.
I would like to chose the path using a `tk.filedialog.asksaveas`...

```
def exportCSV(container):
exCsDi = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
if not exCsDi:
    return
with open (exCsDi.name) as file:
    json.dump(container.Dict, open(file ,'w'))
file.close()
container.leavemini()
```

This does not work, though. 
I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`

I have successfully used `json.dump()` before, just this time I cant seem to see my mistake

Thank you!

Comment: remove  ```.name``` from the 5th line. ```exCsDi``` is already the filename

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful in finding my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution after Michael K. helped me to find a different problem:

```
def exportCSV(container):
exCsDi = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
if not exCsDi:
    return
with open (exCsDi, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(container.Dict, file)
container.destroy()
```